# Why are modules much slower to import in Python 3, and is there a way to address this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, performance

Importing certain modules takes a lot longer in Python 3 compared to Python 2:

```
$ t python2 -c 'import requests'
0m0.174s
$ t python3 -c 'import requests'
0m0.403s
$ t python2 -c 'import bs4'
0m0.256s
$ t python3 -c 'import bs4'
0m0.431s
```

Since some of my projects import both modules and a bunch more, I'm getting complaints from users who notice the latency, which in aggregate is well over a second.

Benchmarks above are Python 2.7.15rc1 vs Python 3.6.7 - latest system Pythons on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, so very popular distributions.

Any idea what's causing this latency on the newer Python, and how I can mitigate this issue?

Comment: What if you compare `python2 -c 'pass'` and `python3 -c 'pass'`?

Comment: Python 3 has always been slower than Python 2 in published benchmarks (though of course there's a lot more to it than that). Generally speaking, newer versions of Python 3 are faster than older ones. I suggest upgrading to the latest 3.7 release. You probably won't get the same speed as you see with Python 2, but hopefully you'll get an improvement over 3.6.

Comment: There are a number of possible issues that could be happening here. For example, the Python 3 modules might be missing `.pyc` files, with some permissions issue preventing the creation of `.pyc` files (or perhaps preventing Python from reading `.pyc` files).

Comment: The normal mitigation for slow startup (for any runtime, in any language) is to run a background service/daemon to do the work, and just have a mechanism to send commands to it to perform actions as desired.

Comment: @user2357112 Python 3 is slower with just `pass` too: 0.074s vs 0.027s for Python 2. So yes, it seems what I'm seeing with imports might be just one symptom of a fairly broad performance regression in Python 3.

Comment: @DanielPryden this are utility scripts distributed to external users, most of whom aren't savvy, and upon whose machines I have no control. Trying to get them all to run a service / daemon is unfortunately impractical.